# Bash - Cycling trough ARP table and storing IPs in a variable

Tags: bash, ssh, network-programming, arp

So if I wanted to connect via SSH to all the devices on a network, using the ARP table to know exactly where to connect, what could I do?

The code would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in $([ARP Table here?])
do
    ssh user@$a true
    echo "Connected to $a"
done
```

I'm not sure on how to store the dinamic IPs in the a variable. Also I'm not sure on the fact that I can use that a variable afterward to connect via ssh, because an IP wouldn't be a int, but more probably a string.

EDIT: After Andrew made me notice that not every device on my network could be in my ARP table, I'm wondering:

Is it better to start from 0 to the maximum value of the current network mask or searching in the ARP table?

Here are the two cases:

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in $(seq 255)
do
    ssh user@172.18.10.$a true
    echo "Connected to 172.18.10.$a"
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in $([ARP Table here?])
do
    ssh user@$a true
    echo "Connected to $a"
done
```

Comment: Probably not a good approach. There's no guarantee that any given local device will actually be in your ARP cache at any given time.

Comment: @AndrewMedico So you are saying that there could be some divices actually on the network but not in my ARP table. I will then edit my question.

Comment: Also, "all the devices" doesn't tell us enough. What kind of devices? Cisco IOS?   JunOS? FreeBSD or Linux? If you're talking about the arp cache on a particular host, you can parse the output of `arp -an` in most operating systems. But listen to Andrew, he speaks truth; your arp cache is ephemeral, and dependent on network activity. ARP is a tool to allow your devices to speak Ethernet with each other, it's not a network management strategy.

Comment: @ghoti Could I flush the ARP Cache, send an ARP Request to every device connected on the network, like in broadcast, and then use it to connect? The devices I'm talking about are PCs that run linux

Comment: Sure, you could do a variety of things. But if you already have a list of devices, why not use that instead of the arp cache? Your SSH will be to a hostname or an IP address, not an Ethernet address. The arp cache on the system initiating these connections is just a tool to allow IP and other higher level protocols to function. [What are you *really* trying to achieve?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @ghoti So how can I find this list of devices connected on my network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution than developing your own scanning tools might be to use something that already exists.

To see what IP addresses are reachable (which as a side effect will populate your ARP cache), you might use [`fping`](http://fping.org/).  It's probably available for your OS or distro.  An example from my local network:

```
$ fping -g 10.1.1.0/29
10.1.1.1 is alive
10.1.1.2 is alive
10.1.1.5 is alive
10.1.1.3 is unreachable
10.1.1.4 is unreachable
10.1.1.6 is unreachable
```

The `fping` command is ICMP-only -- it sends pings.  If your goal is not just to determine what devices exist, but also whether they are answering on the SSH port (22), you could use [`tcping`](http://www.linuxco.de/tcping/tcping.html) or something equivalent.

```
for ip in $(seq -f "10.1.1.%g" 1 9); do
  if tcping -u 200 -q $ip 22; then
    echo "yes: $ip"
  fi
done
```

Another option which might be a little trickier to script would be to use an actual scanning tool, like [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/) (as seen in [The Matrix](https://nmap.org/movies/matrix/trinity-nmapscreen-hd-crop-1200x728.jpg)).

If you're using a network monitoring system, check to see if it has network scanning tools built in.  [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), for example, has a [discovery plugin](http://docs.cacti.net/plugin:discovery).  [Nagios](http://nagios.org) has [quite a few of them](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Configuration/Auto-2DDiscovery).

Comment: Ty very much gothi for everything :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer to your initial question (the one the title introduces).

To read the arp table and iterate over each IP address on it, you can do the following

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in $(arp -n | tail -n+2 | cut -d' ' -f1)
do
    ssh user@$a true
    echo "Connected to $a"
done
```

- `arp` command outputs the arp cache, along with some info
  about each entry.
- `tail` is used to remove the first line, which
  contain the header for the different columns of the output of
  `arp`.
- `cut` removes all the aditional info, leaving only
  the IP address, one on each line.

Comment: Unfortunately, the /proc filesystem is a Linuxism.  There are versions of it for other operating systems, but they are usually not mounted by default, and as far as I've seen they do not include the /proc/net extension.  The OP hasn't specified what operating system is in use here, so it's important to make your answers portable.